# Implementing a Async/Await method returning a task in cli/c++?

Tags: c#, c++, asynchronous

I am trying to implement a interface from a c# class in cli/cpp managed code.

the interface look likes this:

```
public interface IManagedAlgorithmHost<TOptions,TResult> : IManagedAlgorithmHost
{
    Task<TResult> RunAlgorithmAsync();
    void SetAlgorithmContext(IManagedAlgorithmContext<TOptions> context);  
}
```

i figured out how to import the dll and that into my cli/cpp project, but I fail at figuring out if its even posible to create a class in managed c++ that implements that RunAlgorithmAsync method.

```
public ref class MyAlgHost
{
}
```

how do I extend the above c++/managed class with the interface and how do I create the method that returns Task

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `async`/`await`, but you do have the following options available.

1. If you want to implement the method as a true asynchronous method, you'll need to use the Task Parallel Library directly. The [Threading Library](https://github.com/rackerlabs/dotnet-threading/releases) I created recently includes several methods which *may* simplify the implementation of programming language constructs in an asynchronous manner without requiring the use of `async`/`await`. I created the library for exactly this purpose, but did emphasize C#/VB code in the implementation (which uses delegates in many places).
2. If you want to implement the method synchronously, you can use [`Task.FromResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922.aspx) to return a completed `Task<TResult>` instance with the `Result` property set to the return value from your method.